# Access Database Engine could not find object - object is Excel named range

Tags: excel, vba, object, ms-access, oledb

This is something that has had me going round and round in circles for a while now, essentially all I would like to do is to insert the values of an Excel dynamic range into an Access table.

I have had success in doing this by referencing the range as  for example, however to make things a little more self sufficient I would prefer to use a dynamic range.

The code I have is as follows:

```
Sub ExportDistDatatoSql()

Dim cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim STRQUERY As String

Set cn = New ADODB.Connection

With cn
.Provider = "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0"
.ConnectionString = "Data Source=" & ThisWorkbook.Path & "\uMyDB.accdb;"
.Open
End With

ssql = "INSERT INTO Crude_Prods_DB Select * from [Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;DATABASE=C:\TEST\mysheet.xlsm].[n_range]"

cn.Execute ssql

End Sub
```

The error I am seeing is attached and I have checked an [n_range] does exist in the workbook.

[error seen when attempting to insert data into access table from excel named range]

Any suggestions would be much appreciated.

Comment: We don't need to see a screenshot of the error message.  When you encounter that error, go into debug mode, and paste this highlighted text as one line in the Immediate window and press enter at the end of that line: `Debug.Print err.Number; err.Description`  You can copy the output from `Debug.Print` and paste it into your question.

Comment: ...or Ctrl+C will typically copy the text of the message box to the clipboard

Answer (score 1):

I learned this the hard way. A *dynamic range* is resolved only when Excel runs, thus it doesn't exist when you just read the file.

Only a saved and fixed Named Range can be read by Access.

Comment: Thanks for your response, i do have a couple of other questions.

Firstly, if the code above is being executed from excel i.e excel is open, surely the dynamic range would be resolved?  Unless I completely mis-understanding the point.

Secondly, if i change the named range toa static named range, I still see the same error message.  

I think i'm slowly coming to the conclusion that it maybe best just to stick with referencing the range by columns and rows.

Comment: It should work with a static range. But perhaps it doesn't like that the file is already opened? Can you import from another (closed) file? Also, it appears to me as if you _cross the creek to get water_ ... why not just loop the range and add the values to a recordset?